# How can i fill .fbx 3D model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

how can i fix this? (Made in Blender) >>> [capybara](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqYsk.png)

Comment: Looks like the normals are flipped.  I am not familiar with blender, however you should be able to `Select All Faces` and then `Invert`.

Comment: Thanks but the point is in blender looks normal.

Comment: You will likely have better luck on the unity answers site or blender forum, since stackoverflow is geared towards coding questions.  best of luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `recalculating normals` in blender? if that still does not solve the problem then we need screenshot of inpsector with material selected.

Comment: This is called Backface Culling in Blender you need to turn it on in Blender to see if your normals are correct or not. After turning on this Blender and if it still looks normal in Blender you should calculate normals in Unity with importing settings. But I believe you will see this situation in Blender also when you turn on backface culling.